# Delete Method Bool to string error

Tags: c#, client-server

I am trying to build a delete function for a local server database in c#. the code below for some reason it's telling me I am mixing my **deleteOk** with a string.

```
 public bool Delete(string departId)
    {

        bool deleteOk = false;

        try
        {
            DbContext ctx = new DbContext();
            var departments = ctx.Departments;
            var dept = departments.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(dpt => dpt._id == new ObjectId(departId));
            ctx.Delete<Department>(dept, "departments");
            deleteOk = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DALUtils.ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeDAO", "Delete");
        }
        return deleteOk;
    }
```

Comment: Just noticed it after these two guys submitted the answer so thanks for the help :p. I have not been a sleep in the last day or so :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason it's telling me I am mixing my deleteOk with a string

Because you are.

---

You declare the value as a `bool`:

```
bool deleteOk = false;
```

You set boolean values to it:

```
deleteOk = true;
```

And you try to return it:

```
return deleteOk;
```

But the method declares that it returns a `string`:

```
public string Delete(string departId)
```

---

If you want to return a `bool` from the method, have the method return a `bool`:

```
public bool Delete(string departId)
```

C# is a statically typed language.  It won't implicitly convert between types.  So you can't treat a `bool` as a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of your method is a string. Change it to bool and the error is gone...